# MySQL: How to use GROUP_CONCAT with WHERE comparison

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, where-clause, group-concat

I have 2 tables: `groups`: a simple list of group names, and `group_users`: a list of groups and their users, e.g.:

```
group_id user_id
1        2
1        37
1        38
3        14
8        2
8        24
8        27
```

I have a `GROUP_CONCAT` query that is currently working:

```
SELECT g.group_id, g.groupname
,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONVERT(gu.user_id, CHAR(2)) ORDER BY gu.user_id) AS group_members
FROM group_users gu, groups g
WHERE g.group_id = gu.group_id
GROUP BY gu.group_id
ORDER BY gu.group_id;
```

This produces a result:

```
group_id  groupname  group_members
1         Sales      2,37,38
3         Marketing  3
8         Production 2,24,27
```

**My Problem**: I'm trying to get a list of groups a specific user ID is a member of (e.g. here, user_id 2 should produce result rows 1 & 3).

However, when I change the criteria `WHERE g.group_id = gu.group_id AND gu.user_id = 2`, I get:

```
group_id  groupname  group_members
1         Sales      2
8         Production 2
```

The groups are filtered correctly, but the `group_members` list is limited to said ID.

I've seen many SO answers suggest using `HAVING` vs. `WHERE`, but that produces an error. I've tried `JOIN`s, that doesn't work either.

How can I filter the `groups_users` table to only ones with `user_id` of 2, then grab the list of all members of those `group_id`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a query to filter the desired groups:

```
SELECT g.group_id, g.groupname
,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONVERT(gu.user_id, CHAR(2)) ORDER BY gu.user_id) AS group_members
FROM (SELECT group_id FROM group_users WHERE user_id=2) gu1
INNER JOIN group_users gu
ON gu.group_id=gu1.group_id
INNER JOIN groups g
ON g.group_id = gu.group_id
GROUP BY gu.group_id
ORDER BY gu.group_id;
```

Comment: A sub-query to create a temp table, then adding 2 `INNER JOIN`s. A perfect solution that I would not have thought of any time soon. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One option would be using a subquery with `GROUP_CONCAT()` grouped by `group_id` column containing a `having` clause to check out existence of `user_id=2` :

```
SELECT g.group_id, g.groupname, gu.group_members
  FROM `groups` g
  JOIN (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT user_id ORDER BY user_id) 
               AS group_members, group_id
          FROM `group_users` 
         GROUP BY group_id
        HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN user_id = 2 THEN 1 END) > 0
        ) gu
    ON g.group_id = gu.group_id 
 ORDER BY gu.group_id;

+----------+------------+--------------+     
| group_id | groupname  | group_members| 
+----------+------------+--------------+
|  1       | Sales      | 2,37,38      |
|  8       | Production | 2,24,27      |
+----------+------------+--------------+
```

Use grave-accented `groups` as table name, because of being a preserved word.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a7b8826da172561bd9fdcd2511456671)</kbd>

Comment: Points for ` groups ` - which cropped up as an issue in MySQL 8.x.

Answer (score 1):

You can just reference group_users twice, no subqueries needed:

```
SELECT g.group_id, g.groupname
   , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONVERT(gu.user_id, CHAR(2)) ORDER BY gu.user_id) AS group_members
FROM group_users AS ug -- the specified User's groups
INNER JOIN groups AS g ON ug.group_id = g.group_id
INNER JOIN group_users AS gu ON g.group_id = gu.group_id
WHERE ug.user_id = 2
GROUP BY g.group_id
ORDER BY g.group_id
;
```

Also note that this, and every other answer so far, converted your implicit "comma" join query into one with explicit JOINs. This is because the comma join syntax has been considered archaic and hard to maintain for quite a while, and was pretty much replaced by explicit JOIN syntax over a decade ago for all but the simplest queries.

Answer (score 0):

The condition:

```
WHERE gu.user_id = 2
```

removes the rows before aggregation.
Instead you can use a `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT g.group_id, g.groupname
,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT gu.user_id ORDER BY gu.user_id) AS group_members
FROM group_users gu INNER JOIN groups g
ON g.group_id = gu.group_id
GROUP BY gu.group_id
HAVING SUM(gu.user_id = 2) > 0
ORDER BY gu.group_id;
```

Also why do you convert `user_id`s to `CHAR(2)`?
If a `user_id` is greater than 99 it will be truncated.
Use:

```
DISTINCT gu.user_id
```

inside `GROUP_CONCAT()` and MySql will convert the integer value implicitly.

Comment: Ah, the 2-character limitation... it's for a small company. I should adjust to 4 for optimism :)

i need some sort of conversion, as the native `GROUP_CONCAT` result is a BLOB ('0X322...'), even with `DISTINCT`.